# Как при помощи модуля net из electron.js загрузить изображение

Tags: node.js, electron

Так вышло что по некоторым причинам не могу использовать нечего кроме того что есть у electron.js для загрузки файла. Мне необходимо скачать изображение при помощи модуля net. Файл он загружает но вот то что я далее сохраняю через fs программа просмотра изображений не может прочитать, код функции:

```
const {net} = require('electron')
const fs = require("fs");

function  getAndSaveImg(url, nameFile, callback){

    const request = net.request({
        method: 'GET',
        protocol: 'https:',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        path: url,
        useSessionCookies:true
    });

     request.on('response', (response) => {
        let t = ''
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            t+=chunk
        });
        response.on('end', () => { 
            fs.writeFile('./cash/'+nameFile, t, {encoding:'binary'}, callback)

        });
    });

    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    request.end();

 }
```

Comment: я вот такое писал https://pastebin.com/cZ9kkTyk

Comment: На сколько я понял у Вас скрипт заточен на получение json, у меня же проблемы с бинарником а точнее я не могу понять на каком шаге  портятся данные, вроде кодировку и header поставил правильно но все что сохраняется в итоге невозможно прочитать.

Comment: нет, эта штука - универсальна, она работает с картинками и с json. кстати, я забыл `import getStream from 'get-stream';`

Comment: спасибо, я проверю

Comment: В итоге все что собирает и возвращает Ваш скрипт делается у меня на строке t+=chunk, результат тот-же

Comment: вовсе нет. мой скрипт возвращает Stream, который легко запайпить в WritableStream и получить файл с корректными данными, а не так, как у вас